Prove that convex hull of two ellipses symmetric with respect to some line contains ellipse of larger area.
One of the two ellipses is symmetric to another with respect to some line, as on picture, prove that convex hull of these two ellipses contains ellipse of area larger than area of each of the two symmetric ellipses.


What have you tried so far? Where did you get the problem?
